# set textview programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I wanted to set textview programmatically, the below code doesn't seem to work

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);  
textView.setText("game");  
setContentView(textView);
```

Comment: post the full code any exceptions?

Comment: create a simple View and add text view to it

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

to

```
TextView textView = new TextView(Youractivity.this);
```

Comment: what's wrong with `this`? How do you know `this` does not refer to activity context?

Answer (score 0):

remove `setContentView(....);` anywhere before `TextView textView = new TextView(this);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);  
textView.setText("game");  

textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
setContentView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

create `LayoutParams` as following

```
LayoutParams  param=new LayoutParams(w, h);
           textView.setLayoutParams(param);
```